# Cannot use duplicate table name Issu

Tags: sql, hana

We have used the temp table in stored procedure. When we are aborting the stored procedure running and re-execute it again, we are getting the error shown here (In the same session). Could someone please help us to fix the issue?

```
com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: 
[288]: cannot use duplicate table name: "TGK_DATA_PD_001"."CPM_SP_E_CACL_ALL": 
line 64 col 2 (at pos 1649): "TGK_DATA_PD_001"."CPM_SP_UPD_MLADJ": line 58 col 2 (at pos 1323): 
#TMP_TGK_DB_TAGERT_SCEN: line 1 col 37 (at pos 36) - SQLState: HY000 - ErrorCode: 288
```

Stored procedure details:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "CPM_SP_UPD_MLADJ" (IN WFDIM_AZI varchar(30), IN "SESSION_USER" varchar(30)) 
AS


 /*********BEGIN PROCEDURE SCRIPT ************/

    P_PROJ varchar(30);
    P_USER varchar(30);
    
    P_Att1 nvarchar(50);
    P_Att2 nvarchar(50);
    P_Att4 nvarchar(50);

    SCEN_KBN      nvarchar( 2); --FY or CY

    A_COMP        nvarchar(50);
    AC_INCOT      nvarchar(50);
    GALL_VOL      decimal(27, 9);
    ACC_CBU_OF    nvarchar(50);
    ACC_CBU_INSUR nvarchar(50);

    -- FOR LOOP
    LoopCnt     numeric(3,0);
    Cnt         numeric(3,0);
    INPUTNO1    nvarchar(50);
    INPUTNO2    nvarchar(50);
    EOS_DATE    DATE;


    EVENT_DATE TABLE (
        EVENT_SDATE DATE        ,
        ROWNO       bigint      ,
        INPUTNO     nvarchar(50)
    );

    EVENT_DATE2 TABLE (
        EVENT_SDATE DATE        ,
        ROWNO       bigint      ,
        INPUTNO     nvarchar(50)
    );


BEGIN

    P_PROJ := :WFDIM_AZI;
    P_USER := :SESSION_USER;


    CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY COLUMN TABLE #TMP_TGK_DB_TAGERT_SCEN(
            SCENARIO varchar(64) NULL,
            SCENARIO_CY varchar(64) NULL,
            MONTH_NO numeric(4, 0) NULL
        );


    SELECT ATTRIBUTO1, ATTRIBUTO2, ATTRIBUTO4
      INTO P_Att1, P_Att2, P_Att4
      FROM AZIENDA
     WHERE COD_AZIENDA = :P_PROJ;


    -- GET SCKBN
    SELECT TOP 1 ATTRIBUTO2
      INTO SCEN_KBN
      FROM DEST4
     INNER JOIN FORM_DATI FD
        ON FD.TESTO_4       = DEST4.COD_DEST4
     WHERE FD.COD_PROSPETTO = 'FT_IF_010102'
       AND FD.COD_AZIENDA   = :P_PROJ
       AND FD.COD_CATEGORIA = :P_Att4
       AND FD.TESTO_4      IS NOT NULL;

    INSERT INTO #TMP_TGK_DB_TAGERT_SCEN
    (SCENARIO
    ,MONTH_NO)
     (
         SELECT  COD_SCENARIO
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by FY_SP.COD_SCENARIO ASC ) as ROWNO
           FROM SCENARIO_PERIODO FY_SP
          WHERE ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:P_Att1||'01','yyyymmdd'),3) <= FY_SP.DATA_INIZIO
            AND ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:P_Att2||'01','yyyymmdd'),3)  > FY_SP.DATA_INIZIO
            AND RIGHT(COD_SCENARIO, 2) = :SCEN_KBN
          GROUP BY COD_SCENARIO
          ORDER BY FY_SP.COD_SCENARIO
       );

    SELECT COUNT(*), 1
      INTO LoopCnt , Cnt
      FROM #TMP_TGK_DB_TAGERT_SCEN;

    WHILE :Cnt <= :LoopCnt DO


        UPDATE TRG
          SET IMPORTO = DATAS.IMPORTO
            , IMPORTO_VALUTA_ORIGINARIA = DATAS.IMPORTO_VALUTA_ORIGINARIA
            , NOTE = 'CPM_SP_UPD_MLADJ H_'
         FROM DATI_SALDI_LORDI TRG
        INNER JOIN CONTO ACCOUT
           ON ACCOUT.COD_CONTO = TRG.COD_CONTO
          AND ACCOUT.ATTRIBUTO2 LIKE 'H%'
        INNER JOIN #TMP_TGK_DB_TAGERT_SCEN SCEN
           ON LEFT(SCEN.SCENARIO,4) = LEFT(TRG.COD_SCENARIO,4) 
          AND SCEN.MONTH_NO = :Cnt + 1
        INNER JOIN #TMP_TGK_DB_TAGERT_SCEN SCEN_N
           ON SCEN_N.MONTH_NO = :Cnt
        INNER JOIN DATI_SALDI_LORDI DATAS
           ON LEFT(DATAS.COD_SCENARIO,4) = LEFT(SCEN_N.SCENARIO,4) 
          AND DATAS.COD_PERIODO   = TRG.COD_PERIODO
          AND DATAS.COD_AZIENDA   = :P_PROJ
          AND DATAS.COD_CATEGORIA = :P_Att4
          AND DATAS.COD_CONTO     = TRG.COD_CONTO
          AND DATAS.COD_VALUTA    = TRG.COD_VALUTA
          AND DATAS.COD_VALUTA_ORIGINARIA = TRG.COD_VALUTA_ORIGINARIA
          AND DATAS.COD_DEST1     = TRG.COD_DEST1
          AND DATAS.COD_DEST2     = TRG.COD_DEST2
          AND DATAS.COD_DEST3     = TRG.COD_DEST3
          AND DATAS.COD_DEST4     = TRG.COD_DEST4
          AND DATAS.COD_DEST5     = TRG.COD_DEST5
          AND (DATAS.NOTE <> 'N' 
           OR  DATAS.NOTE IS NULL)
        WHERE TRG.COD_AZIENDA   = :P_PROJ
          AND TRG.COD_CATEGORIA = :P_Att4
          AND TRG.NOTE          = 'N';


        Cnt := :Cnt + 1;
    END WHILE;


    -- For EVENT Param-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:P_Att2 || '01','yyyymmdd'), 3)
      INTO EOS_DATE
      FROM DUMMY;

    EVENT_DATE2 =
        SELECT
             TO_DATE(TESTO_1 || TESTO_3 || '01','yyyymmdd') as "EVENT_SDATE"
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TESTO_1 || TESTO_3 || '01','yyyymmdd')) ASC) AS "ROWNO"
            ,RIGHT(TESTO_2, 2) as "INPUTNO"
          FROM FORM_DATI
         WHERE COD_PROSPETTO = 'FT_IF_010109'
           AND COD_AZIENDA   = :P_PROJ
           AND COD_CATEGORIA = :P_Att4
           AND TESTO_1       IS NOT NULL
           ;


    EVENT_DATE =
        SELECT
            EVENT_SDATE ,
            ROWNO       ,
            INPUTNO     
          FROM :EVENT_DATE2
         WHERE EVENT_SDATE <= :EOS_DATE
        ;


--20180725 ADD

        UPDATE TRG 
          SET IMPORTO = DATAS.IMPORTO
            , IMPORTO_VALUTA_ORIGINARIA = DATAS.IMPORTO_VALUTA_ORIGINARIA
            , NOTE = 'CPM_SP_UPD_MLADJ D2 ATL'
         FROM DATI_SALDI_LORDI TRG
        INNER JOIN CONTO ACCOUT
           ON ACCOUT.COD_CONTO    = TRG.COD_CONTO
          AND ACCOUT.ATTRIBUTO2   = 'D2'
        INNER JOIN DATI_SALDI_LORDI DATAS
           ON DATAS.COD_SCENARIO  = 'LAUNCH'
          AND DATAS.COD_PERIODO   = TRG.COD_PERIODO
          AND DATAS.COD_AZIENDA   = :P_PROJ
          AND DATAS.COD_CATEGORIA = :P_Att4
          AND DATAS.COD_CONTO     = TRG.COD_CONTO
          AND DATAS.COD_VALUTA    = TRG.COD_VALUTA
          AND DATAS.COD_VALUTA_ORIGINARIA = TRG.COD_VALUTA_ORIGINARIA
          AND DATAS.COD_DEST1     = TRG.COD_DEST1
          AND DATAS.COD_DEST2     = TRG.COD_DEST2
          AND DATAS.COD_DEST3     = TRG.COD_DEST3
          AND DATAS.COD_DEST4     = TRG.COD_DEST4
          AND DATAS.COD_DEST5     = TRG.COD_DEST5
        WHERE TRG.COD_AZIENDA     = :P_PROJ
          AND TRG.COD_CATEGORIA   = :P_Att4
--MOD 2080918
--        AND TRG.COD_SCENARIO    = 'EY01'
          AND TRG.COD_SCENARIO    IN (SELECT 'EY' || RIGHT('00' || INPUTNO , 2)
                                        FROM :EVENT_DATE
                                       WHERE ROWNO = 1)
--MOD END 20180918

          AND TRG.NOTE            = 'N';


--20180725 ADD END


    SELECT COUNT(*) , 2
      INTO LoopCnt  , Cnt
      FROM :EVENT_DATE;


    WHILE :Cnt <= :LoopCnt DO

        SELECT PRE.INPUTNO ,NXT.INPUTNO
          INTO INPUTNO1    ,INPUTNO2
          FROM :EVENT_DATE PRE
         INNER JOIN :EVENT_DATE NXT
            ON NXT.ROWNO = PRE.ROWNO + 1
         WHERE PRE.ROWNO = Cnt - 1;


        UPDATE TRG 
          SET IMPORTO = DATAS.IMPORTO
            , IMPORTO_VALUTA_ORIGINARIA = DATAS.IMPORTO_VALUTA_ORIGINARIA
            , NOTE = 'CPM_SP_UPD_MLADJ A4D2'
         FROM DATI_SALDI_LORDI TRG
        INNER JOIN CONTO ACCOUT
           ON ACCOUT.COD_CONTO    = TRG.COD_CONTO
          AND ACCOUT.ATTRIBUTO2   IN ('A4','D2')
        INNER JOIN DATI_SALDI_LORDI DATAS
           ON DATAS.COD_SCENARIO  = 'EY' || RIGHT('00' || INPUTNO1, 2)
          AND DATAS.COD_PERIODO   = TRG.COD_PERIODO
          AND DATAS.COD_AZIENDA   = :P_PROJ
          AND DATAS.COD_CATEGORIA = :P_Att4
          AND DATAS.COD_CONTO     = TRG.COD_CONTO
          AND DATAS.COD_VALUTA    = TRG.COD_VALUTA
          AND DATAS.COD_VALUTA_ORIGINARIA = TRG.COD_VALUTA_ORIGINARIA
          AND DATAS.COD_DEST1     = TRG.COD_DEST1
          AND DATAS.COD_DEST2     = TRG.COD_DEST2
          AND DATAS.COD_DEST3     = TRG.COD_DEST3
          AND DATAS.COD_DEST4     = TRG.COD_DEST4
          AND DATAS.COD_DEST5     = TRG.COD_DEST5
          AND (DATAS.NOTE <> 'N'
           OR  DATAS.NOTE IS NULL)
        WHERE TRG.COD_AZIENDA   = :P_PROJ
          AND TRG.COD_CATEGORIA = :P_Att4
          AND TRG.COD_SCENARIO  = 'EY' || RIGHT('00' || INPUTNO2 , 2)
          AND TRG.NOTE          = 'N';


        Cnt := :Cnt + 1;
    END WHILE;


    COMMIT;


    DELETE FROM DATI_SALDI_LORDI
     WHERE COD_AZIENDA   = :P_PROJ
       AND COD_CATEGORIA = :P_Att4
       AND NOTE          = 'N';

    DROP TABLE #TMP_TGK_DB_TAGERT_SCEN;
END;
```

Comment: share your code, else nody can help you

Comment: how does HANA handle scoping of temp tables?  are they created on the fly and only exist for the session?  are they created ahead of time and the data is private to a connection?  is it truly a temp table or just a table the stored procedure creates, uses, then drops?  the error message makes it sound like the proc is trying to create a table that already exists, which should point you towards solutions

Comment: Presumably the SP creates the temp table and deletes it at the end? If you abort the SP, does the code that deletes the temp table not get run?

Comment: Please don’t put information in comments, add it to your question so that everything someone needs to help you is in one place. Also, what you’ve given doesn’t seem to be the full SP code, so isn’t much use. However, given your comment about the SP dropping the table, my previous comment seems likely to provide the solution

Comment: Thanks NickW. I have added the information in the question itself. Yes you're right, When I'm abort the SP the temp table is not getting delete, this is the issue.

Comment: OK - so don't cancel the SP or add some code to it that ensure the temp table is deleted regardless of how the SP ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of a temporary table in this procedure is unnecessary.

Instead, a SQLScript table varible can be used to achieve the same outcome without requiring any creation or removal of tables.

The code for `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE...` and `DROP TABLE...` should be completely removed.

In place of the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE...` command, this command should be used:

```sql
 TMP_TGK_DB_TAGERT_SCEN = 
         SELECT DISTINCT COD_SCENARIO   as SCENARIO
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                    (order by FY_SP.COD_SCENARIO ASC ) as MONTH_NO
           FROM 
                SCENARIO_PERIODO FY_SP
          WHERE ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:P_Att1||'01','yyyymmdd'), 3) <= FY_SP.DATA_INIZIO
            AND ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:P_Att2||'01','yyyymmdd'), 3)  > FY_SP.DATA_INIZIO
            AND RIGHT(COD_SCENARIO, 2) = :SCEN_KBN
          ORDER BY FY_SP.COD_SCENARIO;
```

In the single `SELECT` statement where the temporary table was used, the table variables should be used:

```sql
   INNER JOIN :TMP_TGK_DB_TAGERT_SCEN SCEN
           ON LEFT(SCEN.SCENARIO, 4) = LEFT(TRG.COD_SCENARIO, 4) 
          AND SCEN.MONTH_NO = :Cnt + 1
   
    INNER JOIN :TMP_TGK_DB_TAGERT_SCEN SCEN_N
           ON SCEN_N.MONTH_NO = :Cnt
```

Beyond this common mispractice in HANA (using MS SQL Server style programming with temp. tables) there are a few other issues in the code:

- `SELECT ... INTO FROM DUMMY` : this pattern should generally be replaced by a direct assignment; there is no need for a `SELECT`.

So

```sql
SELECT 
ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:P_Att2 || '01','yyyymmdd'), 3)
      INTO EOS_DATE
FROM DUMMY;
```

becomes

```sql
EOS_DATE =  ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:P_Att2 || '01','yyyymmdd'), 3);
```

- A `TOP 1` clause without an `ORDER BY` allows for arbitrary rows to be returned. Also, `SELECT INTO` without `DEFAULT` clauses may lead to runtime errors, when no records or more than one record is returned.

```sql
 SELECT TOP 1 ATTRIBUTO2
      INTO SCEN_KBN
      FROM DEST4
     INNER JOIN FORM_DATI FD
        ON FD.TESTO_4       = DEST4.COD_DEST4
     WHERE FD.COD_PROSPETTO = 'FT_IF_010102'
       AND FD.COD_AZIENDA   = :P_PROJ
       AND FD.COD_CATEGORIA = :P_Att4
       AND FD.TESTO_4      IS NOT NULL;
```

The best improvement here depends on both the HANA version used and the data in the table. Current HANA versions allow for [DEFAULT values](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/8c738274a3e44694b0d5f709e7db531f.html?locale=en-US) with `SELECT INTO`.
In older versions, one could use a pattern to `UNION` the fallback/default value:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 
    ATTRIBUTO2
    INTO SCEN_KBN
FROM 
    ( SELECT -1 as ATTRIBUTO2 FROM DUMMY 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ATTRIBUTO2
         FROM DEST4
        INNER JOIN FORM_DATI FD
           ON FD.TESTO_4       = DEST4.COD_DEST4
        WHERE 
             FD.COD_PROSPETTO = 'FT_IF_010102'
          AND FD.COD_AZIENDA   = :P_PROJ
          AND FD.COD_CATEGORIA = :P_Att4
          AND FD.TESTO_4      IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY ATTRIBUTO2 ASC;
```